# Specifying two conditions with :if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, validation

I have a model which validates presence of an attribute if a check box is checked in the view.

The code is something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_first_name, :if => :receive_by_email_is_unchecked
```

I am looking to have another condition of this validation.So how do I go about doing this ??

My assumption is that something like this would do:

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_first_name, :if => {:receive_by_email_is_unchecked,:form_first_step_validation}
```

I am not sure if this is the write way of doing it or not ??

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Fastest way: wrap it in a method, and put the logic there.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass method names in an array:

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_first_name, :if => [:receive_by_email_is_unchecked, :form_first_step_validation]
```

Alternatively you can use proc if you don't want to define separate methods just for conditioning validations:

```
validates_presence_of :shipping_first_name, :if => proc { !receive_by_email? && form_first_step_validation }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ryan Bates covered this in one of his first Rails casts
http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations

It's still valid although syntax may be slightly different for Rails v 3 +

I assume you are working on a Rails 2.x app as the syntax you use is not Rails 3 syntax
Rails 3.x syntax would be

`validates :field_1, :field_2, :presence_of => true, :if =>` # Use a proc, or an array of conditions here. see the valid examples and comments that you have already received for this question from @jimworm and @Michał Szajbe

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that will work, but have a look at the source code for validates_presence_of https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb

You can build your own validator to do exactly that